# Swift - array[Any index]?

Tags: arrays, swift, indexing

Okay this is what I'm trying to do:

```
var number = 3
var numberArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
if number = numberArray[one of the indexes] {
// do something
}
```

can anybody help?

Comment: what is `one of the indexes` supposed to do? Do you want to check whether `number` is in the array? Then go for `contains`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, what you want is `contains`:

```
var number = 3
var numberArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
if numberArray.contains(number) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I think you are right.. :D